Iterative process converging on all initial matrices
Question. Suppose $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ is nonsingular. Consider the iterative scheme
$X_{n+1} = X_n + c (A X_n - I).$
The eigenvalues of $A$ are real with $\lambda_{\max}=5$ and $\lambda_{\min}=-1$. Show that there is no value of $c$ such that the scheme converges for all initial $X_0$, but for the modified scheme $X_{n+1}=X_n+C(AX_n-I)$ where $C$ is now a matrix, the iterative method can converge to $A^{-1}$ for all initial matrices $X_0$. Find $C$.
My work. Considering $E_n=X_n-A^{-1}$, I worked out $E_{n+1} = (I+CA) E_n$, so the convergence requires $\left\| I+CA \right\| <1$, which means $\lambda_i (CA) \in (-2,0)$ for all $i$.
My problem. From here, how do I proceed? Knowing $A$ has eigenvalues within $[-1,5]$, how am I supposed to choose $C$ such that the eigenvalues of $CA$ lands within my desired range?

unless $CA$ is diagonalizable, the condition on the eigenvalues is not sufficient. Moreover it is also not necessary since $CA$ may have complex eigenvalues

Depends on what you can use.
A simple solution is $C = -A^{-1}$, but I guess you cannot invert.
Another solution is $C = -A^T/\|A\|^2$.
Frankly, I don't know how you can use the info on the eigenvalues to find a suitable $C$, since they do not tell you about anything about the norm of $A$

I was considering using some transformation or decomposition on $C$ to effectively shift the spectrum, but I don't know the specific transformation. Thanks anyways!
